# Evaluating $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cosh(x+s)^{-2}\cosh(x)^{-2}dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, improper-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

So I have this function:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cosh(x+s)^{-2}\cosh(x)^{-2}dx$$

And when I try to integrate it, I can obtain $0$. And, when I evaluate the limits, it also cancels to $0$. The solution I was given stated that the answer should be some form of:

$$\frac{\cosh(s)\cdot s}{\sinh(s)^3}- \frac{1}{\sinh(s)^2} $$

None of what I'm doing seems to get me the answer and as you can see, it's not like Mathematica even makes the output easy to parse. This is my Mathematica expression:

```
In[42]:= Integrate[Cosh[x + s]^-2*Cosh[x]^-2, x]

Out[42]= -2 Coth[s] Csch[s]^2 Log[Cosh[x]]+2Coth[s] Csch[s]^2 Log[Cosh[s + x]]-Csch[s]^2 Sech[s] Sech[s+x] Sinh[x]-Csch[s]^2Tanh[x]
```

Comment: Maybe try converting to exponentials and see if you can use a substitution to get a rational function under the integral?

Comment: When you write $\cosh(x)^{-2}$ do you mean $\cosh\frac{1}{x^2}$ or $1/\cosh^2(x)$?

Comment: $1/cosh^2(x)$ sorry

Comment: I dont understand how you would get 0 if the integrand is strictly positive.

Comment: I used the substitution $t=tanh(x)$, and got an answer of $\frac{4scosh(s)}{sinh(s)^3}-\frac{4}{sinh(s)^2}$

Comment: Input in Mathematica Integrate[Cosh[x + s]^-2*Cosh[x]^-2, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]

gives  2 Csch[s]^2 (-2 + Coth[s] Log[E^(2 s)]) which simplifies to 4 (-1+s Coth[s]) Csch[s]^2 that is $$4 (s \coth (s)-1) \text{csch}^2(s)$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $x= \frac{t-s}2$ to reexpress the integral as
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac1{\cosh^2(x+s)\cosh^2(x)}dx
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac4{(\cosh t+ \cosh s)^2}dt
$$
Note that

$$\left( \frac{\sinh t}{\cosh t+ \cosh s} \right)’
= \frac{\cosh s}{\cosh t+ \cosh s} - \frac{\sinh^2s}{(\cosh t+ \cosh s)^2}
$$
Integrate both sides
$$I =\frac{4 }{\sinh^2s}\left(-1+\cosh s \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\cosh t+\cosh s}dt\right)
$$
where
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\cosh t+\cosh s}dt
= \frac{2\tanh^{-1}(\tanh\frac t2\tanh\frac s2)}{\sinh s}\bigg|_0^\infty 
= \frac s{\sinh s}$$
Thus
$$I =\frac{4s\cosh s }{\sinh^3s}-\frac4{\sinh^2s}
$$